# How to enable suggestions for autocompletion of commands?

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

In TexShop, you have to keep pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> until you find the correct command for autocompletion. Is there a way to list them while typing, like in TexMaker?

Comment: This was asked again around a year later: [Texshop autocomplete option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362558)