# Texshop autocomplete option

Tags: texmaker, texshop, auto-completion

Is it possible in Texshop to have an autocomplete option like in Texmaker, so that I don't need to press Esc everytime?

What I mean is that [image: Example]

So instead of clicking Esc, it automatically shows you the possible options.

Comment: Hi, welcome. At the surface this looks mostly like a feature request to TeXshop, and as such it isn't something we can handle here (you need to contact the developers of TeXshop for such things). That said, it wouldn't hurt if you were more specific about what you want TeXshop to do. I mean, a user can be an expert on TeXshop, but not know anything about Texmaker, so if you were to explain this better, then a user like that would be able to say if it's possible or not.

Comment: I didn't know how to add an image in a comment, so i've edited the question, anyway I've answered.                                                          So, this feature isn't already included right now? Right?

Comment: No idea, I don't use TeXshop (don't have a Mac). You can't add images in comments, but clarifications should generally edited into the question anyways, so that is the right place for it.

Comment: This was asked once before on this site: [How to enable suggestions for autocompletion of commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294350)